# Behaviour of solution of differential equation at infinity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

Consider the ODE $y' = (1-y)(2-y)$ with initial condition $y(0) = 3$. I have soved this and found the solution $$ y(x) = \frac{e^x - 4}{e^x - 2}$$
which I've checked on Wolfram Alpha. Consider the behaviour of $y(x)$ as $x \to \infty$. By simply taking the limit $y(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

However, now consider $y'$ interpreted as a vector field. The 1 dimensional picture is something like $$--->-->->y=1<-<--<---<--<-y=2->-->---> $$ So I'd expect that solving the ODE for $y(0)=3$ would mean that $y(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ (following the "flow line"). Where am I going wrong in my interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does go to $+\infty$, but as $x$ approaches a finite value, namely $\ln(2)$.

Comment: Can I use the diagram I've drawn in my question to interpret anything about the behaviour of the solutions?

Comment: Your diagram correctly shows that $y$ starts out increasing, and eventually goes to $+\infty$.  Whether this will be as $x \to \infty$ or as $x$ approaches a finite value can't be determined from the diagram: in this case it is a finite value.